# Should the focus regarding iterator performance be in advancement or element access?

Tags: c++, matrix, iterator

### The matters

I have a matrix class which stores a symmetric matrix contiguously.
Since those matrices have the nice property to be axisymmetric (with respect to mirroring at the diagonal), 
storage can be optimized to be a upper or lower triangular matrix.

The following scheme indicates the storage scheme for a 6x6 symmetric matrix stored as an upper triangular matrix.

```
r \ c   0     1     2     3     4     5
   -------------------------------------
 0 |  0  |   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |   5 |
   -------------------------------------
 1 |     |   6 |   7 |   8 |   9 |  10 |
   -------------------------------------
 2 |     |     |  11 |  12 |  13 |  14 |
   -------------------------------------
 3 |     |     |     |  15 |  16 |  17 |
   -------------------------------------
 4 |     |     |     |     |  18 |  19 |
   -------------------------------------
 5 |     |     |     |     |     |  20 |
   -------------------------------------
```

Now I want to design an iterator for rows and columns of that matrix.
I do not want to iterate the actual rows and columns but the rows and columns of the virtually complete symmetric matrix.

Exmaple:

```
for (the_iterator i=matrix.row(2).begin(); i!=matrix.row(2).end(); ++i)
{
    cout << *i << " ";
}
```

This should print the contents of the elements

> 2 7 11 12 13 14

(if matrix is a 6x6 triangular matrix as shown above).

Fortunatelly, the sequence of row `i` equals that of column `i` in case of a symmetric matrix so I only need one iterator type.

The matrix class provides a method to access elements according to their row and column index

```
reference operator() (size_type const r, size_type const c) { /*...*/ }
```

I got two ideas about how to design the iterator. Switching the math from one to another point.

#### 1. Easy iterator advance with matrix reference

I could on one hand store a reference to the matrix, the number of the desired row/column and the current element in this row/column.

```
matrix_type & m;
size_type fixed;
size_type free;
```

This would enable the usage of `operator()` of my matrix class for dereferencing as well as easy iterator advancement.

```
class the_iterator
  // ...
{
  // ...
  reference operator* () const _NOEXCEPT 
  { 
    return *m(fixed, free);
  }
  // ...
  this_type & operator++ (void) _NOEXCEPT
  { // increment then return
    ++free;
    return *this; 
  }
  // ...
};
```

This has one obvious downside: Each call to `operator()` requires the contiguous index in the underlaying memory to be calculated using the row and column indices.

#### 2. Easy dereferencing with pointer to element

On the other hand it would be possible to have a pointer `p` (matrix value_type element pointer) and some control values to control iterator advancement.
In the vertical part (2 -> 7 -> 11; referring to the example above) the pointer needs to advance 5+4 and in the horizontal part (11 -> 12 -> 13 -> 14) the `pointer` needs to change by 1+1+1.
This is not trivial but also not very difficult and can be solved in an algebraic fashion without iteration.

Dereferencing/element access is no long associated with any calculation since `*p` can be used.
This is how I currently do it.

### The question:

Where should I have the "computational work" and which way would you go (and why)?

I can either have

- simple and fast iterator advancement but demanding element access or
- demanding advancement but simple and fast element access.

I tend to the second since the iterator will most likely advance only once per cycle (in a loop), whereas it may be dereferenced multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really, really need to have the data arranged as in your example, I'd first take advantage of the basic character of a triangular array to speed up indexing.  That would make your first choice better:  store a reference to the matrix, the fixed row/column, and the current free index value, and rely on the fast indexing for performance.

The simplest mapping I know for indices of a unitriangular matrix is:

```
int unitriangular_index(int row, int col)
{
    assert(row >= 0);
    assert(col >= row);

    int base = (col * (col + 1)) / 2;

    return (base + row);
}
```

If you can arrange the values that way, accessing a slice of the matrix would look like:

```
int reflected_index(int row, int col)
{
    assert(row >= 0);
    assert(col >= 0);

    if (col < row)
    {
        return (unitriangular_index(col, row));
    }
    else
    {
        return (unitriangular_index(row, col));
    }
}
```

Comment: The storage pattern is in fact a lower triangular which is indexed using the scheme you present here. Eventhough the unitriangular index for the upper triangular as I have it here is calculated `r*N - (r*(r-1))/2 + c - r` which is only "a little" more demanding but not that much. The question actually is about whether "the work" should be done upon dereferencing (as in this/the first case) or advancing (as in the second I presented). You didn't elaborate on why you believe the first will be a better solution.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear:  Given either my formula or yours for accessing elements, the code will be a lot simpler if you do the computation when dereferencing - and I'm always in favor of keeping the code as simple as possible, unless and until performance testing shows there's a bottleneck.